# How to automatically generate reports from Selenium tests on multiple browsers?

Tags: python, html, selenium, report

I'm making autotests on `python` using `Selenium`. I have to make possibility to start multiple tests on a few browsers at one run. I'm trying to use [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html)
with code like this (something is omitted):

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
for test in tests:
  suite.addTests(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test))

outfile = open(reportFile, "w")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile)

for browser in browsers:
  TestParameters.CurrentBrowser = browser
  runner.title = TestParameters.CurrentBrowser.name
  runner.run(suite)

outfile.close()
```

It works good, but... `HTMLTestRunner` doesn't support multiple test runs in one report - it just prints few `HTML` documents in one file. So I need a another way to make reports. I expected to got reports like this:

```
/------------+------+-------\
|            |chrome|firefox|
+------------+------+-------+
|test1       |  [+] |   [+] |
+------------+------+-------+
|test2       |  [+] |   [-] |
\------------+------+-------/
```